# Mysql join to find "missing" "related" rows

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have an ownership relation between two tables,
say `users(int user_id)` and `user_books(int user_book_id,int user_id,int book_id)`
and two additional tables `books(int book_id, varchar book_title, int author_id)` and `authors (int author_id, varchar author_name)`.

Given a specific `user_id` I want to get the books that the user DOES NOT HAVE that where written by authors that he does have other books writen by them.

So if the user has BOOK1 (i.e. there exists a row for this in `user_books`) and does not have BOOK2 and BOOK3 that where written by the same author as BOOK1, I want to get the ids for BOOK2 and BOOK3.

I guess I can do this using a SELECT WHERE NOT IN () but for performance reasons I am looking for a join based solution.

Comment: Have you tried using an outer join?

Comment: as I said, I can write this using  a "select where not in" but I want to use joins. I am aware that it should be somehow done using a left join but I am not sure exactly how.

Comment: I am also having a problem wit the fact that some users might have more then a single user_book already so a join would return the author ID more then once.

Comment: should I start by finding all the books by the "related" authors?

Answer (score 2):

I'd check the performance versus a "not in" or other solution but I believe the following would work:

```
select exist.userId, b.bookTitle, a.authorName  
from (select distinct ub.userId, b.authorId  
         from userBooks ub  
           inner join books b on b.bookId = ub.bookId  
         where ub.userId = @userId) exist  
  inner join Authors a on a.authorId = exist.authorId  
  inner join Books b on b.authorId = a.authorId  
  left outer join userBooks ub on ub.bookId = b.bookId and ub.userId = exist.userId  
where ub.userId is null
```

The derived table finds all the authors that a user likes then the rest of the query finds other books by the same authors

Comment: you are right - that works, but it is far more complicated (as you expected) than using IN and NOT IN. If you do an explain on your query you see there are 4 PRIMARY queries and 2 DERIVED queries (one using a temporary table). Whereas "select * from books where author_id in (select author_id from user_books as ub join books as b on b.book_id = ub.book_id) and book_id not in (select book_id from user_books where user_id = @uid);" has four queries, all using where (and therefore eligible for acceleration with indexes). I agree that measuring both approaches is necessary to pick the best.

Comment: @D Mac - exactly. You can't take a wholesale "don't use NOT IN" approach. Just because it's possible to do it without them doesn't mean you should ... Far better as you've suggested to look at the way the query is processed. I just wanted to demonstrate the possible but I'd recommend based on analysis

Comment: thank you both, I will try and work things out from here.

@D Mac In the syntax you provided there is a missing where user_id = @uid in the first sub query as far as I can tell. and even tough my books table has a an index on author_id  and on book_id  neither is used.

Comment: @KAJ where does the specific user id enter this query?

Comment: In the derived table bit - as per updated answer. Please take note of the performance comments from @D Mac and myself

Comment: @D mac, seeing that I did end up using the NOT IN syntax suggested by you, if you would like to post it as an answer I will accept it. @KAJ my thanks to you as well for your effort and comments.